# How to implement Google authentication using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-api, google-authentication

I am developing a login feature in that user can login into the application using the Google account and get user profile detail. For that, I am creating a project in google developers and it's verified by me.

I try with this reference **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgFIsVr26zg)** but when I try with this that is give me the error of "Disallowed user agent" and gives me the error of the open in safari or chrome when I try with the iPhone(iOS devices).

I also go through some other references like "Xamarin. Auth" but it doesn't work for me. When I set a redirection URL with **clientId:/oauth2redirect** *or* **the Package Name(Bundle Identifier):/oauth2redirect** . It gives me an exception of Not valid redirect Uri.
I also try to add JSON and p12 file on respective device-specific projects and set bundle resource but it doesn't work me.

If anyone has solution to this without using WebView than help me.

Comment: In the `Authorised redirect URIs` option, have you input the valid redirect URIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this plugin from CroosGeeks

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GoogleClientPlugin

Here is the sample app:

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GoogleClientPlugin/tree/master/GoogleClient/GoogleClientSample

This is not using the WebView. The documentation is also quite good.

Comment: I not able to get any source can you please share me zip file over here because when I try to use that I can't get where to start from your code.

Comment: just follow the steps from here https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GoogleClientPlugin/blob/master/GoogleClient/docs/GoogleFirebaseConsoleSetup.md